# What does syncing do?

Tags: sync

My samsung galaxy s4 mini offers two syncing methods : Samsung syncing and Google syncing.
My phone has important notes in the standard built-in app "S memo" and important recordings in the built-in voice recorder.
Does any of these two syncing methods sync this stuff ? Under "app syncing" maybe ?
If so, does that truly mean I can retrieve it if I lose my phone and buy a new Samsung (resp Android) phone ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the apps your using but in general I'll audit/limit network traffic with a firewall just to be safe. As you've not specified if root or not I'll suggest two that I've had good experiences with.

[NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall) uses a neat trick with Android VPN built in options to allow for both logging and blocking network access; per interface (cell antenna or WiFi) and per application.

[AFWall (root required)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) uses `iptables` and a fancy user interface to allow for even finer grain control.

Do be aware that blocking apps that require network access, such as a browser, will break the apps' features until unblocked. But using either will allow for you to find out exactly to whom each app is talking to in each network state... you can even catch dumb apps trying to make connections when in *airplane mode*.

Comment: Are you sure this was for me ? If so I'm very sorry but I don't see how that relates to my question

Comment: It is indeed. Using a firewall like either of the above will allow you to see what apps get chatty on the network when using either syncing mode or any network mode. It's far more information than just on the two apps you're asking about. Try the no root firewall, go to the logs after setup and turn syncing on and off.

Comment: Right I get it, please forgive my ignorance !

Comment: Forgiven ;-) and no worries as it's kinda a round about way of answering what any app is doing with the network... mostly.... firewalls only are honest if the host OS is... more technical route would be to run Wi-Fi on your phone and run packet capture software on another device but I left that off as you didn't seem concerned with your phones trustworthiness.

Comment: Oh and if you do wish to go deeper into what bits are going over the network you can check my [other answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/96635/82480) to how to check if your phone is secretly sending data even after using a firewall. It's not a good idea to read it before bed though as it's more on the subject of detection of spyware and less on the subject of syncing and *valid* feature use that normal applications preform.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the built in voice recorder but the if you sign in and sync your samsung account then s_apps will be backed up